# Read image (or video) into javascript?

Tags: javascript

On my webpage I have `<img src="//example.com/path/image.jpg" id="foo">`. In my testing environment I'm executing a userscript and I'd like the userscript to get the image (binary, base64 encoded, it doesn't matter) and POST it to `http://localhost:1234/debug/`. Later on I may make it more sophisticated and POST the hash but right now I have no idea how to get the image.

I'm not sure if this matters but the image is on my site and I may move it to a static domain.

Comment: @E.Sundin That looks like a decent solution. However I'm a little worried. Will it convert it to a bitmap/uncompressed and force me to save as a png image? Then I won't have the original file/filesize/hash (base64 hash is acceptable). I probably don't need a video solution but maybe in 2017 (the link is 09) there's a more straightforward solution. I'll need it to test it

Comment: Don't quite know what you want to achieve (so we might be facing an XY problem), but there are a few options you could consider: send the URL rather than the file to the server (and the server could then download it if needed), or load the image using Ajax. Both have different drawbacks.

Comment: The duplicate link is indeed correct in that the **question** is actually a dupe, but the answers there aren't that correct. Passing an image to a canvas will modify this image (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting). So I'll post an answer on the dupe target instead of yours.